# Can I download this software on Ubuntu or is it not compatible

Tags: 12.10

I need to download this Secunia PSI 3.0 software inspector on my computer but my only working operating system is Ubuntu 12.10. Is it possible for me to download this on Ubuntu. I'm really new to Ubuntu so I am sorry if this is a very dumb question.

Comment: YOu don't need this WINDOWS patching software on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Secunia PSI 3.0 is a Windows-only program. While you could download this and run it through WINE, you really wouldn't need it. Software on Linux is very secure as it is.

So yes, you can download it. But you would need to run it through the WINE Windows Program Loader.

To download WINE, you can go [here](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) and follow the steps or you can type `sudo apt-get install wine1.5` in the CLI (command line interface, or Terminal).

Comment: +1 for "Yes, you download it", but I'm not too sure that it is wise to run such things, WINE or not.

Comment: I agree; I don't run any sort of anti-virus or software scanning programs on my Ubuntu.

I figured I should at least give an answer as well as providing helpful information (that info being the fact that he doesn't need to download it).